# DocuSign API with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, docusignapi

**UPDATED WITH WORKING SOLUTION**

I'm trying to integrate the DocuSign API using ColdFusion and keep running into an issue. I am able to authenticate successfully and retrieve the base URL. However, when trying to create the envelope with a single recipient and document, I get an error stating that the "boundary terminator" is not found in the request (when it clearly is).

I know this questions is similar to another post here but that was from a while ago and was never completely answered.

I first read in the PDF document:

```
<cffile action="READBINARY" file="Agreement.pdf" variable="docData">
<cfset docData = BinaryEncode(docData,"Base64")>
```

I then create the envelope definition in XML using the  element to include the encoded binary PDF data:

```
<cfset envelope = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=""http://www.docusign.com/restapi"">
                <status>Sent</status>
                <emailSubject>eSignature request</emailSubject>
                <emailBlurb>Please sign the document</emailBlurb>
                <recipients>
                    <signers>
                        <signer>
                            <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                            <name>eCS Buyer</name>
                            <email>XXX@XXXX.com</email>
                            <tabs>
                                <signHereTabs>
                                    <signHere>
                                        <documentId>1</documentId>
                                        <pageNumber>3</pageNumber>
                                        <xPosition>10</xPosition>
                                        <yPosition>100</yPosition>
                                    </signHere>
                                </signHereTabs>
                            </tabs>
                        </signer>
                    </signers>
                </recipients>
                <documents>
                    <document>
                        <name>Agreement.pdf</name>
                        <documentId>1</documentId>
                        <fileExtension>pdf</fileExtension>
                        <documentBase64>#docData#</documentBase64>
                    </document>
                </documents>
               </envelopeDefinition>">
```

Lastly, I POST the information:

```
<cfhttp url="#baseURL#/envelopes" method="POST" resolveurl="Yes" throwonerror="No">
<cfhttpparam name="X-DocuSign-Authentication" type="HEADER" value="<DocuSignCredentials><Username>#userName#</Username><Password>#password#</Password><IntegratorKey>#integratorKey#</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>">
<cfhttpparam name="Content-Type" type="HEADER" value="application/xml">
<cfhttpparam name="Accept" type="HEADER" value="application/xml">
<cfhttpparam name="Content-Length" type="HEADER" value="#Len(envelope)#">
<cfhttpparam name="request_body" type="BODY" value="#envelope#">
</cfhttp>
```

I tried changing the TYPE attribute for the request body to XML and FORMFIELD but is still doesn't work. I even tried changing the envelope to JSON format to no avail.

The error that is generated is:

```
<errorCode>INVALID_REQUEST_BODY</errorCode><message>The request body is missing or improperly formatted. The XML request does not match the expected format. </message></errorDetails>
```

I have been struggling with this for weeks. Any guidance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely an issue with extra CRLF (i.e., extra line breaks). See the answer in this other forum post for an example of what the full request structure should look like:  [Docusign : Unable to create envelope from document in restapi v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478727/docusign-unable-to-create-envelope-from-document-in-restapi-v2/20480957#20480957).

**UPDATE #1**

Looks like your XML request body is missing information about the Document.  Try adding a **documents** element as a child element of **envelopeDefinition** (i.e., as a peer element to **recipients**):

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns=""http://www.docusign.com/restapi"">
    ...            
    <documents>
        <document>
            <name>Agreement.pdf</name>
            <documentId>1</documentId>
        </document>
    </documents>
    ...
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Also, make sure the document bytes that your sending in the subsequent part of the request are not encoded.

**UPDATE #2**

I don't know much about ColdFusion, but this line of your code makes it look like you're (base64) encoding the byte stream that you're including in the Request:

```
<cfset docData = BinaryEncode(docData,"Base64")>
```

This could be causing your latest issue, as I don't believe DocuSign will accept an encoded byte stream when it's included in the manner you're currently utilizing.

If you must base64-encode the byte stream, you could add a **documentBase64** property under the **document** element to contain the base64-encoded byte stream. (See page 104 of the DocuSign REST API Guide -- http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf.) If you utilized this approach, your request would no longer need to be a 'multipart' request, since the document bytes would be included in the XML portion of the Request Body (not in a subsequent/separate part). Here's an example of what the Request would look like, if the base64-encoded byte stream was included within the **documentBase64** element:

```
POST /restapi/v2/accounts/ACCOUNT_NUMBER/envelopes HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.docusign.net
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS","Password":"PASSWORD","IntegratorKey":"INT_KEY"}
Content-Type: application/xml

<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
    <accountId>ACCOUNT_ID</accountId>
    <status>sent</status>  
    <emailSubject>eSignature request</emailSubject>
    <emailBlurb>Please sign the document</emailBlurb>
    <recipients>
      <signers>
        <signer>
         <email>johnsEmail@outlook.com</email>
         <name>John Doe</name>
         <recipientId>1</recipientId>
         <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>  
         <tabs>
            <signHereTabs>
                <signHere>
                    <documentId>1</documentId>
                    <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                    <xPosition>10</xPosition>
                    <yPosition>100</yPosition>
                </signHere>
            </signHereTabs>
        </tabs>
        </signer>
      </signers>
    </recipients>
    <documents>
        <document>
            <name>Agreement.pdf</name>
            <documentId>1</documentId>
            <fileExtension>pdf</fileExtension>
            <documentBase64>BASE64-ENCODED-BYTE-STREAM</documentBase64>
        </document>
    </documents>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Since the document bytes are included within the XML portion of the request, the request no longer needs to be multi-part -- simply pass the XML Request body as I've shown above, and that's it.

Comment: Thank you Kim Brandl and @Ergin. I updated my code with your line break suggestion but I now get a different error. I now get:  `NO_DOCUMENT_RECEIVED  The document element did not contain the encoded document, or there is a problem with the encoding. No documents were found in the request.`

Comment: Ok, I added the <documents> element and was able to successfully create/send the envelope with a basic text document but when I try it with a PDF I'm getting: 

`UNABLE_TO_LOAD_DOCUMENT  Unable to load the document. Unable to load Document(1). Error: the document is corrupt, rebuilding failed`. 

I checked the document and there are no security restrictions. I was also able to upload the document as a template in the DocuSign UI. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know Cold Fusion, but this part of your code:  <cfset docData = BinaryEncode(docData,"Base64")>  -- makes it seem like you're (base64) encoding the byte stream that you end up writing to the DocuSign request. I don't think DocuSign will accept a base64-encoded string -- that may be causing your issue.

Comment: Updated my answer with UPDATE #2.

Comment: Updated my answer to include a code sample for sending the document bytes as part of the XML request body (within the "documentBase64" element).

Comment: I believe Kim's right, you're latest issue is probably because you are base64 encoding.  Try removing that and see if it works...

Comment: I updated my original post to use the <documentBase64> element and now I get a different error. Perhaps I'm not posting the correct Content-Type header value (since it's no longer a multi-part)? With you suggestions, I feel I'm close to getting this to work.

Comment: **SUCCESS!** I had the Content-Type and Content-Disposition in the envelope body. I removed those leaving ONLY the XML envelope definition and it worked. I'll update my original post with the working solution. Thank you Kim Brandl and @Ergin for all you assistance.

Comment: Glad to hear that you've got everything working now -- nice work!

Answer (score 2):

The error is most likely due to the extra CRLF you have after the document bytes and before your closing boundary `--MYBOUNDARY--`.  You have this:

```
#docData#

--MYBOUNDARY--
```

Try changing that to this without that extra CRLF:

```
#docData#
--MYBOUNDARY--
```

For reference you can check out the [DocuSign API Walkthrough for sending a signature request on a document](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument).  Each of the different language versions shows you how the outgoing request body should be formatted.