# Attempting to test Docusign REST API in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, docusignapi

I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847326/docusign-api-with-coldfusion) and am using it to test the DocuSign REST API in my ColdFusion app. It is the whole of it. I am not not very familiar with the ColdFusion language and am pretty sure I am not handling a response from the server in any way through this request. I do not receive an error and I think that is why and the document/email are not sent.

Can anyone point out where my errors are and help me build in code that will return the error so that I can further troubleshoot the issue? Thanks!

```
    <cffile action="READBINARY" file="875487865.pdf" variable="docData">
    <cfset docData = BinaryEncode(docData,"Base64")>

    <cfset envelope = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=""http://www.docusign.com/restapi"">
            <status>Sent</status>
            <emailSubject>eSignature request</emailSubject>
            <emailBlurb>Please sign the document</emailBlurb>
            <recipients>
                <signers>
                    <signer>
                        <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                        <name>John Doe>john@doe.com</email>
                        <tabs>
                            <signHereTabs>
                                <signHere>
                                    <anchorString>1SI</anchorString>
                                    <documentId>1</documentId>
                                </signHere>
                            </signHereTabs>
                        </tabs>
                    </signer>
                </signers>
            </recipients>
            <documents>
                <document>
                    <name>875487865.pdf</name>
                    <documentId>1</documentId>
                    <fileExtension>pdf</fileExtension>
                    <documentBase64>#docData#</documentBase64>
                </document>
            </documents>
           </envelopeDefinition>">

           <cfhttp url="https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information/envelopes"        method="POST" resolveurl="Yes" throwonerror="No">
                    <cfhttpparam name="X-DocuSign-Authentication" type="HEADER" value="      <DocuSignCredentials><Username>MY_USER_NAME</Username><Password>MY_PASSWORD</Password><IntegratorKey>MY_INT_KEY</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>">
                    <cfhttpparam name="Content-Type" type="HEADER" value="application/xml">
                    <cfhttpparam name="Accept" type="HEADER" value="application/xml">
                    <cfhttpparam name="Content-Length" type="HEADER" value="#Len(envelope)#">
                    <cfhttpparam name="request_body" type="BODY" value="#envelope#">
            </cfhttp>
```

Comment: Start by dumping the cfhttp scope after the [cfhttp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html) call to see what response/response code you get back ie `<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">`. See the linked documentation for details about the returned variables.

Comment: @Leigh  results of cfdump.  Cache-Control no-cache
Connection close
Content-Length 0
Date Tue, 19 Aug 2014 21:32:07 GMT
Explanation The URL provided does not resolve to a resource.
Http_Version HTTP/1.1
Status_Code 404. Header HTTP/1.1 404 The URL provided does not resolve to a resource. Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains Connection: close Date: Tue, 19 Aug 2014 21:32:07 GMT Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Length: 0.

Comment: I have not used docusign, but noticed the other thread mentioned *"..I am able to authenticate successfully and retrieve the base URL*. 1) Did you authenticate first? 2) Given the 404 error are you certain the above really is the correct URL?

Comment: @Josh see the answer I just posted, you're not hitting a valid URL

Answer (score 0):

Just as Leigh suspected, you are not hitting a valid DocuSign endpoint.  I see your POST URL set to this:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information/envelopes
```

Where did you get this URL from as it's not valid?  You need to go through the "Making your First API call" section of the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) to learn how to properly login (authenticate) and create an envelope / signature request.

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/first-api-call

Comment: The url was provided in another post on stackoverflow. I was using it as a template. I compared the URL to the .NET application I built and I thought the url matched. This isn't my first API call but it is the first from my coldfusion site.

Comment: So does that mean my answer resolved your issue?  If so can you please accept as the solution?  Thx